# How to disable a link tag to open fancybox mentioned in href url?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, fancybox

In a ASP.NET Web Application, facnybox of jQuery is used on button click.
As mentioned in link: http://fancybox.net/howto

```
<a id="lnkEmail" href="../Email/Default.aspx" runat="server">
 <div id="DivBtnEmail" class="button" runat="server">
  <asp:ImageButton ID="BtnEmail" ToolTip="Send Email" CssClass="image" ImageUrl="../img/tlb_list_email.gif" OnClick="BtnEmail_Click" runat="server" />
 </div>
</a>
```

In some cases during application, there is a need to disable the buttons which opens fancybox.
I used asp:button property to disable the button.

```
BtnEmail.Enabled= false;
```

But, due to link tag it still works and open the url mention in link href in a fancybox.

How to disable a link tag to open a fancybox ?
I've tried the solution mention in link : [how to disable link in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3222420/how-to-disable-link-in-jquery)
But, it didn't work for me.
Any help ???

Comment: You have an `ImageButton` nested inside an `a` tag, and both have an onclick handler that does something different. If you disable the inner `LinkButton` the other `a` still works. Besides that I think nesting 2 elements with different onclick handlers is a good recipe for confusion. Can you not remove the `a` and add the `href` attribute to the `LinkButton`'s `NavigateUrl` property?

Comment: Well, I cann't remove the a tag because it is necessary according to http://fancybox.net/howto to use fancybox. But, I can remove the server side event handler BtnEmail_Click on image button click. But, after removing it still open fancybox because it is mentioned in a href url.

Comment: You may need to define `In some cases during application` : what is the condition? what are the cases? you could filter "those cases" adding a class to that link and bind only links to fancybox without that class.

Comment: Well, this button is along with other buttons in toolbar at the top in a window adn below the toolbar there is a gridview. I have check if gridview contains rows then this data can be emailed  to specified address else email button should be disabled.

Comment: `... I cannot remove the a tag because it is necessary..` is not necessarily true, you could actually fire fancybox within the event handler of that element. BTW, what version of fancybox?

Comment: The ASP.Net `LinkButton` results in an `a` tag in the browser. I cannot believe that fancybox sees the difference between an `a` tag that you typed and an `a` tag that is the result of a `LinkButton`. Surely it must be possible for fancybox to work on the `LinkButton`'s `a` tag. And then you can control the `LinkButton` to make the whole thing `disabled` or not.

Comment: What does `OnClick="BtnEmail_Click"` handler do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#<%= BtnEmail.ClientID %>').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a return false; That way, JS doesnt return the event handler.

```
$('#lnkEmail').click(function() {
if (conditions) return false;
// else do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some kind of selector for fancy box that allows you to be more flexible. 
If you’re selecting html elements where fancybox will be applied using class then you can create another identical class but named differently and then use that.

This doesn’t require additional javascript but it will require additional CSS definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Above discussion helps me to figure it out how to disable the link tag. I disable the link tag from server side where I was enabling/disabling the other buttons w.r.t conditions.
It was the "Disabled" property which needs to be updated accordingly.

this.lnkEmail.Disabled = true;